# How to prevent a convex optimization from being unbounded?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm novice in optimization and have a convex optimization function of form $\sum_{i,k} p_{k,i}*\log{p_{k,i}} $ to minimize with the following constraints:

$\forall i,  a_i = \sum_{k=1}^{m} b_k. p_{k,i}$

$\forall k, k=\sum_{i=1}^{m} p_{k,i}$

$0\leq p_{k,i} \leq 1$

$1\leq i,k \leq m$

$0\leq a_i \leq 1$'s and $0 \leq b_k \leq 1$'s are known and $m=160$.

The values of $b_k$ and $a_i$ comes from my data set. I use [CVX](http://cvxr.com/) optimization tool and it finds a solution after 6,7 iterations. However in my actual problem I need to use approximated $b_k$ and $a_i$. Using the approximated values the solver immediately says its "unbounded"! Could someone help me why it happens? As far as I understand an optimization becomes unbounded when the optimal solution moves towards -Infinity, but I don't understand why it is the case here? Any chance to relax the constraints somehow to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the problem is not unbounded, since ignoring all but the bound constraints on $p_{k,i}$ you have that the objective attains its maximum of 0 at $p_{k,i} \in \{0,1\}$ and its minimum of $-m^2e^{-1}$ at $p_{k,i}=e^{-1}$.

I'm not familiar with that particular software package, but one possible issue is that although the limit of $x\log x$ is well-defined from the right as $x\to 0$, a naive calculation will give `nan`. You might try giving lower bounds on $p_{k,i}$ of $\epsilon > 0$ instead of zero and see if that solves the problem -- alternatively, you could try making the substitution $p_{k,i} = e^{q_{k,i}}$, which eliminates numerical issues with the objective (I haven't checked how nasty this makes your constraints, though.)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the solver is actually solving the dual of your problem and that your primal problem is infeasible and the dual is unbounded.  What was the value of cvx_status returned by CVX?